# The Tags Derabanan and Oral Law

Tags: support, specific-tag, tag-synonyms, tags

***Closely Related:*** https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/the-tag-deorayta-deoraita

Could the descriptions of the two tags "Oral-Law" and "De-Rabbanan" be clarified - to clarify which one is to be used, and when?

Could an alternate spelling, tag-synonym be provided: [de-rabbanan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Talmudic_principles#De.27oraita_and_Derabanan)? rabbinic-law?

Or: is "oral-torah" intended to be a tag-synonym? ; "an also:" of "derabanan"?

Answer (score 1):

Oral Law and Scriptural Law is a distinction concerning the transmission modality. Rambam largely discussed the status of Drashot from 13 measures, and Ramban contested him. So this domain is a little complex. But some scriptures are sustained by oral transmission according to all. So Oral can be Deorayta.

Derabanan: this is a rabbinical addition. sometimes, the scripture itself can give indication how to enact. Most enactments and decrees follow a scriptural model or example in an other domain.

Summary Oral Law !== Derabanan.
Scriptural study of verses !== deOrayta

Comment: **A.)** Sorry for not clarifying sooner - I added a closely related question regarding "Torah-Law", "De'Oraita" - http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4143/the-tag-deorayta-deoraita **B.)** So there are three tags then, that could use some "disambiguation" : de'rabbanan, de'oraita, and oral-law. **C.)** Perhaps, in practice, here : "talmudic-law", "mishnaic-law", "shulkhan-arukh" could fall into de'rabbanan - and try to avoid the debate altogether. **D.)** Perhaps "de'oraita" could be reserved for discussion of torah-law and scriptural-law, derived directly from the text?

Comment: : "talmudic-law", "mishnaic-law", "shulkhan-arukh" --> For me it is talmudic study or oral law. Talmudic study is a kind of learning. this tag is pointing a connotation, contrarily to grammary of scriptures or philosophy of More nevuchim and Sefer Hayikarim. or Kabbalistic or Chassidutic discussion. Orayta and Rabanan is inside the study of laws, the talmudical study and concern the different nuances of dinim